# Failed to start the Kernel, bad address in system call argument during the process of Jupyter

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, kernel

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LAotk.png)

```
Failed to start the Kernel. 

Failed to start the Kernel 'db_env (Python 3.10.12)'. 

View Jupyter log for further details. listen EFAULT: bad address in system call argument 127.0.0.1:9000
```

It was fine to run the ipynb codes until I faced the another error message
"zmq.error.ZMQError: Bad address (addr='tcp://127.0.0.1:9003')."

During fixting the error, I changed the VSC settings like below,
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6vgT5.png)

```
    "jupyter.jupyterCommandLineArguments": [
        "--port=9000"
    ]
```

(after doing this, Python code, which was working normally, also began to fail to start the kernel)

and doing something more in anaconda prompt that I can't remember exactly(sorry to this).

I thought maybe anaconda env is the reason of that error so created the new env
but I clicked the "Select another kernel..." in VSC, see this buffer permanently
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iioAB.png)

System path, Kernel install, VSC restart, check the install of jupyter package,
all these things are checked before

How could to fix this problem? please tell me more infomation about it. Thank you